# Certificate pinning not working in Native android Mobilefirst 8.0 app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In IOS the certificate pinning is working. But in android certificate pinning is not working.

Below is the code snippet of certificate pinning.

```
try {
           WLClient wlClient = WLClient.createInstance(context);
          WLClient.getInstance().pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey("ProdCert.cer");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MFPClient",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            try {

                URI url = new URI("/adapters/TestAdapter/getFeed");
                WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest(url,WLResourceRequest.GET);
                request.send(new WLResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {
                        Log.d("MFPClient",wlResponse.toString());
                        // Toast.makeText(context,wlResponse.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
                        Log.d("MFPClient",wlFailResponse.toString());
                        // Toast.makeText(context, wlFailResponse.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
```

Below is the Logs at the client side

09-20 20:20:16.460 31459-31459/? I/FtBuild: getRomVersion mRomVer=3.6
09-20 20:20:16.608 31459-31459/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
09-20 20:20:16.623 31459-31459/? D/FEEDBACK: analyticsUrl=null analyticsApiKey=null
09-20 20:20:16.624 31459-31459/? W/FEEDBACK: Failed to invoke feedback mode since Analytic context is null
09-20 20:20:16.637 31459-31459/? D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(175:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:175;Function:ASN1_get_object

The above is the logs that is different from the app logs without certificate pinning. Remaining contains the server informations.

In the above code I see a OpensslErr. How to be sure that certificate pinning is happening successfully in native android client side code. There is no exception associated with the logs. That means that, the file is there and it is not invalid cert. But how to be sure that MFP Certificate pinning is successfully happened.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the MobileFisrt sdk version you are using ?

Comment: Use this line in build,gradle 
compile 'com.ibm.mobile.foundation:ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation:8.0.2018060105'
Let me know if it works

Comment: Is it s the same certificate that's working well in iOS? And what Android version are you on? Is it specific to a version or do you see the issue across devices?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?